# Parallel Coordinates Plot

Tags: r, plot, legend

I have a dataset like this:

```
    HR_1 HR_2 HR_3 HR_4 label
    0.1  0.05 1.5   1.6  1   
    0.04 0.15 1.0  1.6   1 
    1.1  2.05 2.5   1.6  0
```

And I want to create parallel coordinates plot where my X axis is 1,2,3,4 and Y axis is my data. Moreover I want that the color for each line be same for all lines with the same label.

Right now I am using plotmd from EMcluster package that does what I want, but does not create a legend for the color behind the line, so I do not know to each class each color corresponds to.

Comment: Please show your code for `plotmd`

Comment: plotmd(snapshots[,1:4],class = snapshots$label)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GGally:: ggparcoord()

```
library(GGally)
df$label <- as.factor(df$label) #label should be a factor
ggparcoord(df, columns = 1:4, groupColumn = 'label',
           scale = 'globalminmax')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the legend with the `legend` function. The hard part is finding what colors to use.

```
library(EMCluster)

plotmd(snapshots[,1:4],class = snapshots$label)
legend("bottomright", legend=unique(snapshots$label), lty=1, 
    col=color.class[unique(snapshots$label)%%length(color.class) + 1])
```

[image: Parallel Coordinates]

To find the colors, I typed `plotmd` to look at the code for the plotmd function. You can see how the colors were created there. Notice that it colors the lines *by the class* - in your case, the label - so there is no distinction between rows 1 and 2.

Comment: I just want a two line legend showing the color of each label.